# Saving pandas styler object in anyway

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

Here's a styler object with a background gradient:

[image]

I'm just looking for anyway to save it as is. Have tried using .render() but not sure what to do with that HTML code, and from reading other questions on the subject it seems there is no current way to save these. Is there a hackish way to do it?

Here is the array:

```
array([[ 0.264     ,  0.271     ,  0.285     ,  0.289     ,  0.329     ],
   [ 0.053     ,  0.051     ,  0.045     ,  0.038     ,  0.031     ],
   [ 0.006     ,  0.007     ,  0.009     ,  0.01      ,  0.01      ],
   [-3.98650106, -3.95728537, -3.99767582, -4.20624136, -3.54186842],
   [-3.22600677, -2.87623307, -2.03420988, -1.54443176, -1.41006671]])
```

and the line of code I have:

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',low=.09,high=.18,axis=1)
```

Comment: would you mind to define "as is"? I don't know such file format...

Comment: sure - as is as in with the current style (background gradient)

Comment: do you want to save it as file, as digital picture, as a printed piece of paper, something else?

Comment: at this point, whatever is easiest - a png would be nice though

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible data set and your code, which produces this colored DF?

Comment: just updated them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from Pandas 0.20.0 you can easily save it to Excel file:

```
 df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',low=.09,high=.18,axis=1) \
   .to_excel('d:/temp/a.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159423/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu-saving-pandas-styler-object-in-anyway).